# Lecture note on Elliptic PDE

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Can someone please suggest me some good lecture notes (not books) on Elliptic PDE?

I am reading the book by Trudinger at my own and in the book there are many lemmas whose proofs are quite long (and boring). That's why I am searching for lecture notes to see what are the calculations I can skip during first reading.

Edit: I am now interested to learn some parabolic PDE as well. I will appreciate any lecture note / reference on parabolic PDE (especially those references which are useful for application of parabolic PDE in geometric flows).

Comment: I suggest the Elliptic PDE by Han and Lin (Courant Lecture Notes).

Comment: I taught an undergraduate course on linear elliptic pde, but it is probably too elementary for you. The notes are here: http://euclid.ucc.ie/Mckay/pde/introduction-to-partial-differential-equations.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Luigi Ambrosio has a great set of lecture notes.

Comment: Could you provide a link to these notes?

Comment: http://cvgmt.sns.it/media/doc/paper/1280/PDEAAA.pdf